# V-lang shows V panic: array index out of range error for valid indexing of array after V panic is encountered once

Tags: arrays, vlang

There is this new programming language [V-lang](https://vlang.io/) being created by Alex Medvednikov. I'm using V-lang version 0.1.11 currently. I can declare an array in V-lang like below :

```
a := [1,2,3]
// or, mut a := [1,2,3]
```

I tried to get the last item of this array like :

```
>>> a := [1,2,3]
>>> println(a[-1])
V panic: array index out of range: -1/3
>>> println(a[a.len -1])
V panic: array index out of range: -1/3
```

Each time, it shows :

> V panic: array index out of range:

Now just after this, if I try to get the items from the array, then still it shows the same error :

```
>>> println(a[1])  
V panic: array index out of range: -1/3
>>> println(a.len)
V panic: array index out of range: -1/3
```

Where as, if we tried to get the items from the array before once we have had encountered `V panic`, it would have printed the same without any error, like a fresh instance in the terminal :

```
>>> a := [1,2,3]
>>> println(a.len)
3
>>> println(a[1])
2
```

Why does V-lang shows `V panic` for valid indexing every time after once we encounter `V panic` beforehand ?

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a bug in V REPL. You can file an [issue here](https://github.com/vlang/v/issues)

Unlike Python, V-lang doesn't have this feature to get elements from the end of an array with negative indexes

```
a := [1,2,3]
a[-1] //isn't valid
```

The [official documentation](https://vlang.io/docs#arrays) is short and precise

> ```
> mut nums := [1, 2, 3]
> println(nums) // "[1, 2, 3]"
> println(nums[1]) // "2" 
>
> nums << 4
> println(nums) // "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
>
>
> nums << [5, 6, 7]
> println(nums) // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"
>
> mut names := ['John']
> names << 'Peter' 
> names << 'Sam' 
> // names << 10  <-- This will not compile. `names` is an array of strings. 
> println(names.len) // "3" 
> println('Alex' in names) // "false" 
>
> // We can also preallocate a certain amount of elements. 
> nr_ids := 50
> ids := [0 ; nr_ids] // This creates an array with 50 zeroes 
>
>  //....
> ```

Comment: my_array#[-1..][0]